# First assembler program

Tags: unix, assembly, printf, scanf, att

I am trying to compile my 1st Assembler program for UNIX, but get a lot of errors. For example, this code (expected to read and write a number from keyboard) gives me "Segmentation fault" message:

```
.data
.code32
printf_format:
  .string "%d\n"
scanf_format:
  .string "%d"
number:
  .space 4

.text 
.globl main
 main:

 pushl $number
 pushl $scanf_format
 call scanf
 addl $8, %esp

 pushl number
 pushl $printf_format
 call printf
 addl $8, %esp
 movl $0, %eax
 ret
```

Comment: It works for me. How are you assembling it into an executable? With this specific program, you should be able to just use `gcc myprog.s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works fine, if you compile it with `gcc -m32 example.s`. If you use a GAS/LD-combination, you cannot terminate it with `ret`. Use instead:

```
pushl $0
call exit
```